# Unresolved external symbol - MySQL API C++

Tags: c++, mysql, connection

Hey I've had nonstop problems with SQL. I'm trying to get some experience because I know it's a vital part of the industry. I got it working with C#, but now I'm working on connecting to a database in c++. I have the project properly linked and what not. Here's my code and the errors I'm getting.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <mysql.h>
 #include <iostream>
 MYSQL mysql;
 MYSQL_RES result;


using namespace std;
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {

    mysql_init(&mysql);

if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "*******", "MyDatabse", 0,       NULL, 0))
{
    printf("Failed to connect");
}


return 0;

    }
```

and the errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32    c:\Users\Zack-074\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MySql\MySql\MySql.obj
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 c:\Users\Zack-074\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MySql\MySql\MySql.obj
Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   c:\users\zack-074\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MySql\Debug\MySql.exe   1
```

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Now that you've posted your code, you might want to change your root password.

Comment: LOL thank you. It's too easy to post that.

Comment: What version of connector do you use - C++ or C? I recently saw similar problem when it linked with C version 6.02, but generated linking errors "unresolved external..." with C++ version 1.1.

Comment: Alright now I'm linking with the c++ connector, but I'm getting even more errors.

Comment: Error 1 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fd' c:\program files\mysql\mysql server

Comment: Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 291
Error 3 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 291
Error 4 error C2065: 'SOCKET' : undeclared identifier c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 470
Error 5 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 's' c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 470

Comment: Error 5 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 's' c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 470
Error 6 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 471
 7 IntelliSense: identifier "SOCKET" is undefined c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 291
 8 IntelliSense: identifier "SOCKET" is undefined c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\include\mysql_com.h 470

Comment: Check this thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ec3ef279-ee31-47e5-a349-8a17e05b3a94. You may try C connector, or to struggle to get rid of linking errors with C++ version using extern "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are linker errors. In other words, you don't appear to be having any problem compiling to object files but are running into difficulties when attempting to link those object files into an executable.

One solution that pops immediately to mind is to manually specify the location and/or name of the library you wish to link against. In VS2010, right-click on the project you're working on and select Properties. From there, open up the linker options and specify the directory in which the library you want to link against.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already did that. MySQL 5.5 doesn't have a lib/opt directory though. I used the lib/opt from the c++ connector. Could that be the problem? I honestly have no clue what could be wrong. I followed a tutorial by the book.

Comment: [link]http://lstigile.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/using-libmysqld-with-microsoft-visual-c-2008-express/[/link]

Comment: Sorry. http://lstigile.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/using-libmysqld-with-microsoft-visual-c-2008-express/

Comment: You're attempting to compile code in Visual Studio that relies on MySQL. In order to do this you need to do two things: (i) specify the location of the MySQL header files and (ii) specify the location and name of the MySQL library you're linking the code against. If you're getting LINK errors when building the project, your problems are with step (ii).

Comment: I don't know where the MySQL library is. I'm assuming you link it in Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library directories?

Comment: Yes, that property should be set to the folder that contains the library you wish to link against.

Answer (score 0):

Open a VS command prompt (or just any prompt and execute `vsvars32.bat`) and then use the compiler as follows:

```
cl /nologo /W4 /EHsc /MD my.cpp /ID:\Opt\MySQL5.5\include ^
   /link /LIBPATH:D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib libmysql.lib
```

The ^ character is just for line continuation (for better display here). The important thing is to tell the compiler about the include directory and the linker about the lib directory for MySQL and then specify `libmysql.lib` as file to be linked. That will put code in your EXE to load the DLL at runtime.

```
dir my*
13.04.2012  19:53               342 my.cpp
13.04.2012  19:53             6.144 my.exe
13.04.2012  19:53             9.762 my.obj
```

Adapted the code to go without `stdafx.h`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

MYSQL mysql;
MYSQL_RES result;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "***", "test", 0, NULL, 0))
    {
        printf("Failed to connect");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry. I don't understand. The linker in c++ always confuses me. Where do I enter the compiler code?

Comment: No matter what I put as the .cpp it says file not found. I tried MySql.cpp, my.cpp, and it still won't work.

Comment: My example file is named `my.cpp`; yours might have a different name. It is convenient to `cd` to the directory where your source file resides so you don't have to type the full path. But it almost sounds like you've never used the command line ... if that is so you should familiarize yourself with the basics; use Google to do so.

Comment: Is there another way to go about this? I'm seventeen and a novice with C++. I know the basics, but I'm much more proficient in C#. Surely there's a more simple way.